# Avoid P2P issues with multi-level NATs with uPNP

Tags: nat, upnp, peer-to-peer

What is the best solution to make a peer-to-peer application workable with multi-level NATs without having to manually open ports on the router? E.g. one application is using uPNP to traverse one NAT, but what if there is a multi-level NAT (e.g. ISP NAT)? I know you can set up a relay server to initiate hole-punching, but is there no easier solution, like in the form of a protocol running on the application itself?